# Don't know how to fix Popup message opening when not needed

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I've been trying to make a website login with HTML and Javascript and it works fine except for one problem. The first login information logs in, but the else popup message shows! How do I fix this?

```
function Login(form) 
{
    username = new Array("alex364981");
    password = new Array("Codylewis");
    page = "user2" + ".html";

    if (form.username.value == username[0] && form.password.value == password[0]
            || form.username.value == username[1] && form.password.value == password[1]
            || form.username.value == username[2] && form.password.value == password[2]
            || form.username.value == username[3] && form.password.value == password[3]
            || form.username.value == username[4] && form.password.value == password[4]
            || form.username.value == username[5] && form.password.value == password[5]
            || form.username.value == username[6] && form.password.value == password[6]
            || form.username.value == username[7] && form.password.value == password[7]
            || form.username.value == username[8] && form.password.value == password[8]
            || form.username.value == username[9] && form.password.value == password[9])
    {
        self.location.href = page;
    }

    username = new Array("test");
    password = new Array("this");
    page = "user1" + ".html";

    if (form.username.value == username[0] && form.password.value == password[0]
            || form.username.value == username[1] && form.password.value == password[1]
            || form.username.value == username[2] && form.password.value == password[2]
            || form.username.value == username[3] && form.password.value == password[3]
            || form.username.value == username[4] && form.password.value == password[4]
            || form.username.value == username[5] && form.password.value == password[5]
            || form.username.value == username[6] && form.password.value == password[6]
            || form.username.value == username[7] && form.password.value == password[7]
            || form.username.value == username[8] && form.password.value == password[8]
            || form.username.value == username[9] && form.password.value == password[9])
    {
        self.location.href = page;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Either the Username or Password is Wrong.\nPlease try again.");
        form.username.focus();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: could you mock up something in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) ?

Comment: `'Multiple exclamation marks', he went on, shaking his head, 'are a sure sign of a diseased mind.'` ([Terry Pratchett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Pratchett))
This is not meant to be insulting, just a little reminder that it is sufficient to use only one of them. This improves readability a lot.

Comment: I hope this is just for testing... you are aware this is NOT how you implement authentication. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication

Comment: you can mock up a isolated example using the link I sent you so we can better understand / assist you with your problem.

Comment: Why do you have two username/password checks?

Comment: for two users i want the users when logged in to go to different pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The else block is only applicable to the second if check

```
username = new Array("test");
password = new Array("this");
page = "user1" + ".html";

if (form.username.value == username[0] && form.password.value == password[0] || form.username.value == username[1] && form.password.value == password[1] || form.username.value == username[2] && form.password.value == password[2] || form.username.value == username[3] && form.password.value == password[3] || form.username.value == username[4] && form.password.value == password[4] || form.username.value == username[5] && form.password.value == password[5] || form.username.value == username[6] && form.password.value == password[6] || form.username.value == username[7] && form.password.value == password[7] || form.username.value == username[8] && form.password.value == password[8] || form.username.value == username[9] && form.password.value == password[9])

{
    self.location.href = page;
}
else {
    alert("Either the Username or Password is Wrong.\nPlease try again.");
    form.username.focus();
}
```

You should be getting the successful login from the first if block.

You should use a flag to check if any of the logins succeeded and use the flag to display the error message.

Try this:

```
function Login(form) 
{
    flag = false;

    username = new Array("alex364981");
    password = new Array("Codylewis");
    page = "user2" + ".html";

    if (form.username.value == username[0] && form.password.value == password[0] || form.username.value == username[1] && form.password.value == password[1] || form.username.value == username[2] && form.password.value == password[2] ||  form.username.value == username[3] && form.password.value == password[3] || form.username.value == username[4] && form.password.value == password[4] || form.username.value == username[5] && form.password.value == password[5] || form.username.value == username[6] && form.password.value == password[6] || form.username.value == username[7] && form.password.value == password[7] || form.username.value == username[8] && form.password.value == password[8] || form.username.value == username[9] && form.password.value == password[9])

    {
        self.location.href = page;
        flag = true;
    }

    username = new Array("test");
    password = new Array("this");
    page = "user1" + ".html";

    if (form.username.value == username[0] && form.password.value == password[0] || form.username.value == username[1] && form.password.value == password[1] || form.username.value == username[2] && form.password.value == password[2] || form.username.value == username[3] && form.password.value == password[3] || form.username.value == username[4] && form.password.value == password[4] || form.username.value == username[5] && form.password.value == password[5] || form.username.value == username[6] && form.password.value == password[6] || form.username.value == username[7] && form.password.value == password[7] || form.username.value == username[8] && form.password.value == password[8] || form.username.value == username[9] && form.password.value == password[9])

    {
        self.location.href = page;
        flag = true;
    }

    if(!flag) {
        alert("Either the Username or Password is Wrong.\nPlease try again.");
        form.username.focus();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: do i just add that to the first?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Looping through your array should clean up the code and readability. This will also make it easier to expand later.

```
function Login(form) 
{
    username = new Array("alex364981");
    password = new Array("Codylewis");
    page = "user2.html";

    var numOfUsers=10;
    for(var i=0;i<numOfUsers;i++)
    {
        if (form.username.value == username[i] && form.password.value == password[i])
        {
            self.location.href = page;
            return true;
        }
    }
    //All possibilities exhausted, Show error.
    alert("Either the Username or Password is wrong.\nPlease try again.");
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Also beware that users can view the source code for your html and get the username and password directly from the function. It's best to hide it in a php script or a database.

Comment: The else should go outside the loop.

Comment: @ATOzTOA potatoe potatado (Updated nevertheless)

Comment: How can people view the javascript? Its in a seperate file

Comment: @user1877134 Even if the javascript is in a different file you still have to link to it with the `<script src="YourJavascriptFile">` which users can right-click in their browser, chose to "View Source" then look for your `<script>` tag and navigate to that file. php executes on the server, not the client and therefor users can't view the code in the file, just what the server sends them.